# Upgrade individual feature in WIX feature-tree without repair other features

Tags: wix, windows-installer, installation, setup-project

I'm using Wix 3.10 to build a MSI installer. After installation, the user can perform three actions - change, repair and uninstall. The installer contains several features. There is a situation where in one (or several) of the features there is a change and there are other features (without changes). The user wants to remove one of the untouched feature via the feature tree using a line "Entire feature will be unavailable" and leave the modified features intact. By default the line "Will be installed on local hard drive" is installed for all features and the installer repair the changed functions. How to make that at run after installation the installer by default did not repair feature. Only if the user chose to repair feature the installer would repair the desired features.

Any help would be appriciated,

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You mention features without changes and modified features. If that means that the installed product has had files or registry entries changed or removed, then the way to stop them being repaired is give them a null ComponentId and manage them yourself. as it says here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368007(v=vs.85).aspx

A repair from that dialog repairs the entire product.

However it's also possible that the application and the install need better integration so that resources are not installed and then removed, thus causing the possibility of repair in a number of ways.